# Слово "опариш" - літературне?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88) знаходжу статтю на дану тематику, таким чином роблю висновок, що літературне:

> **Опариш** — личинка м'ясної мухи. Використовується як наживка у рибальстві та багатий на білок харчовий продукт для відгодівлі птахів та риб. Є об'єктом напівпромислового розведення.

Для перевірки звертаюся у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/oparysh), однак статті такої не знаходжу. То ***чи літературне слово "опариш / опариші"*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знаходимо це слово в Етимологічному словнику укрїнської мови:[image]

Також [російсько-український](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) народний сучасний словник 2009 дає варіант "опариш" як переклад російського "опарыш". Як бачимо, слово справді схоже на російський варіант, тому можна його замінити таким українським словом, як [гробак](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghrobak) (личинка комах або жуків, що живе в землі),

Крім того, якщо ми говоримо про "опариша" для ловіння риби, то варто зазначити, що в російській мові він ще може називатися "[блёвка](https://russian_ukrainian.academic.ru/124524/%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)". У такому випадку згідно з [Російсько-українським академічним словником](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) потрібно використовувати варіант "наживка".

Отож робимо висновки, слово "опариш" бажано не вживати, а замість нього використовувати слова "гробак" або ж "наживка" (залежить від контексту).

Comment: Додам, що в квадратні дужки «Етимологічний словник української мови» бере, здається, діалектні слова.

Comment: Однак _гроба́к_, як я розумію — це просто фонетичний варіант слів _роба́к/хроба́к_, тобто [майже синонім](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/290) до _черв'я́к_. У той час, як _опа́риш_ — це личинка конкретного виду мухи (специфічніше значення).